# Bash variable starting with "-e " does not store

Tags: bash

I am trying to store the string "-e test" in a bash variable. For some reason, it removes the "-e " part from the string. I cannot figure out how to escape this.

Test script:

```
var="-e test"
echo $var
```

Expected output:

```
-e test
```

Actual output:

```
test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your variable is expanded such that:

```
echo $var
```

becomes:

```
echo -e test
```

Where `-e` is a valid argument to `echo`. The variable is being stored correctly, but you're using it in a way that doesn't print it out correctly.

To ensure that there aren't unintended consequences like this, simply put quotes around the variable when using it:

```
echo "$var"
```

Which would be expanded by the shell to:

```
echo "-e test"
```

Comment: I don't know of any versions of `echo` that do this, but in principle `echo "-e test"` could cause `echo` to try to treat "`e`", space, "`t`", "`e`", "`s`", and "`t`" all as command options (just like `ls -la` treats "`l`" and "`a`" both as options), and probably get an invalid option error. The safe and portable way to print strings that might start with "-" (and/or contain backslashes) is `printf '%s\n' "$var"`.